# Casting from an interface object to an object of a class that implements it?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

I am trying to cast an interface object:

```
ScreenController startScreenController = nifty.getScreen("start").getScreenController();
```

(ScreenController is an interface)

to an object of a class named PrisonStartScreenControl:

```
startScreenController(PrisonStartScreenControl).setNifty(nifty);
```

^ but this line causes an error. I know that the startScreenController object is equal to a PrisonStartScreenControl, so how would I be able to cast the interface to its implementor-class?

Comment: You should tag your question with the language you are using to get more attention.

Comment: @simbo1905 Thanks, I forgot to. Got my answer though :D

Comment: so you don't care that someone else may have the same question and cannot find it? :-) it only takes a moment to edit it and make it a better question to help others

Comment: @simbo1905 whoops. I'm kind of new to this, so I didn't notice/consider the edit button

Comment: no problem. be sure to vote up both questions, answers and comments you think are high quality. that awards kudo points. also be sure to click the tick box to accept the best answer to your questions. good luck!

Comment: @simbo1905 Thank you for your kindness; also, how do you suggest that I get my first 15 points so that I can vote people.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cast needs to be on the left side of the variable to be cast, not the right, e.g:

```
((PrisonStartControl)startScreenController).setNifty(nifty);
```

But, why are you casting anyway? setNifty() should be a method on the interface so no need to cast.

Comment: Wow.. I didn't realize order mattered. I thought it was like multiplication. Thank you very much.